# Which Android satnav software can provide full integration with a custom app?

Tags: android, navigation, gps

You can launch Google's Navigation software from an intent, but that is the limit of your app's control.

Do any of the other SatNav packages (including non-free) provide better integration?

In particular:

1. Stopping navigation and closing SatNav.
2. Setting waypoints.
3. Embeddable within another app's layout.
4. Allowing another app to set and update a text field during navigation.
5. Allowing another app to configure features of the navigation.

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking into this for a little while now, and it seems CoPilot Live has a version (CoPilot Professional) that supports at least some of your requirements, but you can't buy it on the market and I've been trying to phone them to find out how to get it, but nobody ever answers the phone in their UK office.

Sygic also apparently has an integration API, and you can buy the appropriate version directly, but I've had bad experience with Sygic in the past (downloaded a free trial version of their software that expired immediately after I spent the best part of a gigabyte of my data allowance downloading maps), so would rather avoid it.

Navigon supports an intent similar to google navigation, but no more than this.

Would still love to hear about other options for this.